# Variable expansion inside single quotes

Tags: shell, variable-expansion

I am quite new to shell scripting.

I have the following script:

```
out="FAILURE"
curl -X POST -d 'json={"json":"message"}' http://localhost:8888/json.tail.test
```

I want to replace "message" with the `$out`'s value. I tried different ways but could not get that done. Can someone please suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
out="FAILURE"
curl -X POST -d 'json={"json":"'$out'"}' http://localhost:8888/json.tail.test
```

Basically, enclose everything except `$out` inside single quotes.  Single quotes protect double quotes but suppress the expansion of variables like `$out`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
out="FAILURE" curl -X POST -d 'json={"json": $OUT}' http://localhost:8888/json.tail.test
```

You just need to literally replace `"message"` with `$OUT`

Comment: That won't expand the `$OUT` part.  Also, the expansion of `$OUT` needs to be inside double quotes as per OP's requirement.  Please see my answer below.